# Rundeck[passing parameters between the jobs]

Tags: rundeck

I have a job which calls another rundeck job, I want to pass parameters between the jobs. I can only pass options from the 1st job to 2nd job, i want results(output) of the 1st job to be passed to the second job as an argument.

Example: 1st job content.
set -x; 
sql_file=/apps/$env/test${buildnumber}.sql;
echo $sql_file

I want to call 2nd job, and pass sql_file location as the variable

I can refer the 2nd job and give options of the 1st job as an argument, i cannot find a way to give the output of the 1st job as an arguemnt to the 2nd job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I capture output from one Rundeck step to be used in a later step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860091/how-do-i-capture-output-from-one-rundeck-step-to-be-used-in-a-later-step)

Answer (score 0):

Rundeck 2.9 will support this ability. It is not released yet, but you can try the beta version here http://rundeck.org/news/2017/06/20/rundeck-2.9.0-beta1.html

Comment: Hello @greg 
Thanks for suggesting, I also have another query, is there any way to get notifications from the job when it hits the time out limit that i've specified.

Comment: Hi @Greg Schueler - it seems this feature is not actually supported as per your comment on the pull request? "@DarwinJS to answer your question, yes it applies to workflow or node steps. The data captured in a Node context is associated with the node, and is available in later node steps on the same node, but can be referenced explicitly if necessary. It is not supported for Job Reference steps" (https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/pull/2482]