# Rundeck: how to pass authentication credentials from a job to another?

Tags: rundeck

In RunDeck, I need to use the output of one job as a input to another. I plan to do it the way outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42982556/10335). Basically, I'd have a master job and it would call the other two jobs.

My problem is that the jobs in my RunDeck installation have access control, so I'd need to pass the authentication info from the master job to the jobs that are started from the command line.

How would I pass this authentication info?

BTW, my company uses RunDeck version 2.5.1, a somewhat old version.

Comment: Are you talking about authentication provided by rundeck? the user can login Rundeck ui, but still need another layer of auth to run certain jobs?

Comment: @Yang: the user logs and starts my job. My job calls another rundeck job. This second call must authenticate to rundeck. I want to know if I can passthrough my credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer versions of Rundeck, it is possible do [pass data between Steps](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/howto/passing-variables.html). The link leads to the feature documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `username` from [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/docs/manual/jobs.html#context-variables), but not password.

You can create a password filed in your first job, and pass that password as command line variable to second job.

I don't know how you can authenticate with rundeck command line, but you can use http call and use rest api...